# how to specify an command line argument with a variable in bash

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I would like my bash script to take either 2 or 3 arguments with the last argument always being the input file to open. So the index of argument should depend on how many arguments provided. I know this can be realized by if statement, like:

```
if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
  INFILE=$3
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
  INFILE=$2
fi
```

..open file to read...

However I was hoping this to be done by a one liner which would look like this:

```
INFILE=$($#)
```

It does not work though. Same thing with INFILE=$"$#". Is it possible to specify index of argument directly with "$#"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using 
`INFILE="${@: -1}"` to get the last argument.

Comment: I've had this in my arsenal for some time too, but I've never understood why it works.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing a well known limitation in shell.  :-)

You could get the last argument by stepping through the existing arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ ! -z "$2" ]; do
  shift
done

echo "Last argument: $1"
```

In Bourne (non-Bash) shell, you could do this with `eval`, which is evil:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval "echo \"Last argument: \$$#\""
```

If you don't need portability outside bash, you can also use the `@` array:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Last argument: ${@: -1}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do indirect referencing of an array, so `${!#}` would also work.